# Words 2007 Windows 10 Auto corrects gives me some weird English choices when it already knows i write in French

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

now and then I write in French and I am a terrible speller besides my keyboard is not very good with accents.
So, When Words works well as I type, it shows me the errors (in French) and I have the choice to accept the correction or, better, go to auto correct and if it is appropriate chose the correct option and all is well since for my next document in French all these words will be auto corrected.
Now the problem I encounter sometimes is when I go to auto correct instead of showing me a list of french words (although if I right click on the red underlined word it will give me the alternative french correctly spelled list of words for me to chose)yes instead, It will have some inappropriate words in English!
Here is an example. 'Esperons' (let's wish) If I look at Auto Correct I will get: **B** in bold and with a green arrow then the words 'But'- 'yet', 'However'. And below it, again with the **B** then 'Buy','purchase', 'obtain by paying money'!
Here I have to state that I had this word written twice in my text and on the first instance it showed me only the top entry, but in the second instance it showed me these 2 entries?
...But all is not too bad, and you may wonder why. As I'm writing this I'm also testing my document to get it right here. And would you believe it? If I accept this strange entry it actually works!
And here is the result: espérons as you can see the acute accent is on the word as it should be
If I had R clicked on my underlined word in this case "esperon" it would have shown me 2 French words
1 espérons 2 éperon ('horse' spur)and I would have chosen option1. But next same entry would also need to be corrected.
The only problem with this would still be that if I needed the second word i would not get it as it would only auto correct me with the first one "espérons"! not a spur at all but quite a stir, wouldn't you think?
This function when it works well is so good as you can increase your auto correct as much as you want in a different language despite an English keyboard and also no worry too much about accents and difficult to remember spellings...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Windows software you installed, French or English, and then what language version of Office you have, the AutoCorrect Libraries on you system are automatically setup to match. Saying that another way, the AutoCorrect Libraries (ACL) are language specific.

Based on what you have said, it sounds like you potentially have ACLs that contain a mixture of language items and that would be caused by the Styles you are using, and how they are setup.

Language is a text Style attribute, just like Bold, or Italic. If you use an Style that is marked for English (or whatever your default language version of Office is on your system) and you type text in French and then proof and edit, including adding AutoCorrects or spellings to your default dictionary ... then you are going to have a confused looking ACL as well as a default spelling dictionary.

The better way to do this for multi-language writing/editing is have dedicated language version Styles and use those for when you are writing and editing in an alternate language. When you setup a New Style and apply a Language attribute to it, if you do not have an ACL for that specific Language on your system, Word will create it.

The ACL files Word uses are in the following path:
C:\Users<Your Home Directory>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office

The file MSO1033.acl is English autocorrects and MSO1036.acl is French.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you R M :) this is very clear although a little out of my depth. From a practical user point I was just wandering why at some stages it was working perfectly well but at others...like i described.  At least I found one more helpful things about this anomalie. The weird result I get also comes with several options 1,2,3 etc and those options seem to match the 'French' option/s I can see if I only R click on the misspelled word. ie I wrote 'Chere' without an accent and when I R clicked on it it gave me 4 options so in A/corect just follow the list order to get it working. (no + room here!)